# Remove the underline from a JLabel text

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I used to underline a JLabel text once clicked this code:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
Font font = label.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

So now I need to restore it to its first state (without underline) once another JLabel is clicked what shall I change?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: How about `attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_OFF);`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,however, there is no attribute called `UNDERLINE_OFF` or something similar

Comment: Great it works! ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_OFF` is not a real constant. So I consulted the [`TextAttribute#UNDERLINE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#UNDERLINE):

> ```
> public static final TextAttribute UNDERLINE
> ```
>
> Attribute key for underline. Values are instances of `Integer`. The default value is `-1`, which means no underline.
>
> The constant value [`UNDERLINE_ON`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextAttribute.html#UNDERLINE_ON) is provided.
>
> The underline affects both the visual bounds and the outline of the text.

And it turns out the default value is `-1`. So to revert the text back to not being underlined just use:

```
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer `attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, -1);` doesn't work for me.

But:

```
label.setFont(new Font(font.getName(), font.getStyle(), font.getSize()));
```

works!